# Python3 Error writing to csv file.

Tags: python-3.x

When I try to write in the file it reports error:
 fo.write(';'.join(row+[\n]))
                                ^
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character

> ```
> import re
> import csv
> #import sys
>
> with open('input.csv', 'r', encoding='UTF-8') as fi, open('output_data.csv', 'w',encoding='UTF-8') as fo:
>     reader=csv.reader(fi,delimiter=';')
>     #for row in csv.reader(fi,delimiter=';'):
>
>
> DESCRIPT1=[]
> ID1=[]
> ASSIGNMENT_NAME1=[]
> TER1=[]
> INFO1=[]
>
>
> for i,row in enumerate(reader):
>     DESCRIPT1.append(row [0])   
>     ID1.append(row [1])
>     ASSIGNMENT_NAME1.append(row [2])
>     TER1.append(row [3])
>     INFO1.append(row [4])
>
>     row[4] = re.sub()
>     fo.write(';'.join(row+[\n]))
> ```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Not enough rep to leave as comment but...

The error is coming from the newline character, in particular the backslash ` in your code. It is expecting whitespace afterwards and the code to continue on the next line.

Is it possible that you're meaning to have your newline character quoted instead of square brackets? `fo.write(';'.join(row+'\n'))`